# Creating a batch file to rename TXT files based on content (removing inappropriate syntax)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, rename

I am trying to create a batch file that will allow me to rename all files in a folder based on text located within the test file itself.  I have pasted the first four lines from the text below:

```
09-Nov-16  07:50 AM                              HAND-HELD DRIVER REPORT                                              PAGE:  1 
                                             XYZ COMPANY - AR1    

    DATE > 11/09/16    DRIVER > 1010    DRIVER NAME > Mike Smith TRUCK > 4719
```

I am trying to name each folder DATE-DRIVER NAME-TRUCK.  I also need to drop the "/"'s in the date field.  Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: I am only see two lines.

Comment: I've reformatted the data - please check that this is correct.To format, select the information to be posted and press `{}`

Comment: So you are interested in the fourth line and want to use the respective strings after the `>` symbols, right? Could you please provide the derived name from the given sample text file? Please clarify what you want to be renamed -- the files or the folder (you mentioned both). And please share your own attempts to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 SET "oldname=%%x"
 SET "newname="
 SET "drivname="
 REM detect a line with 4 ">"
 REM Process only the first found in a file
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-5delims=>" %%a IN (
  "%%x") DO IF NOT DEFINED newname IF "%%e" neq "" (
  REM process date into %%i, %%j, %%k
  FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=/ " %%i IN ("%%b") DO (
   REM build drivname
   CALL :procname %%d
   REM build new filename and rename file
   CALL :build %%k %%i %%j %%e
  )
  IF NOT DEFINED newname ECHO %%x NOT renamed
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:procname
IF "%2"=="" GOTO :EOF
SET "drivname=%Drivname% %1"
shift
GOTO procname

:build
IF NOT DEFINED drivname GOTO :EOF
SET "newname=%1%2%3-%drivname:~1%-%4"
IF /i "%oldname%" neq "%newname%" (
 ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%oldname%" "%newname%"
)
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Relatively simple:

Process each filename to `%%x`. With that filename, look for a line containing 4 `>` When that line is found (`%%e` will be non-empty) then the date will be in `%%b`, so parse it into `%%i,j,k` and process the name+TRUCK string in `%%d`. Finally, build the elements together - year in `%%k`, month in `%%i`, day in `%%j`, trucknumber in `%%e` and drivername in %drivname%.

The `:build` routine ensures that `drivname` exists and the builds the new filename from the supplied parameters and `drivname`. If the new and old names are the same (case-insensitive) then the rename would produce an error (file has already been processed previously) so skip the rename. Since `newname` is established in the `:build` routine, once a rename has happened, it won't be repeated.

Finally, if there was no `newname` set up, then the file hasn't got a line of the required format, so report that fact.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try, change BaseFld to fit your environment

```
@Echo off
Set BaseFld=Q:\Test\2016-11\10\
Set Files=*.txt
PushD %BaseFld%

For %%A in (%Files%) Do For /f "tokens=2-5 delims=>" %%B IN (
  'findstr "DATE.*DRIVER.*DRIVER.NAME.*TRUCK" "%%~fA"'
    ) Do Call :Rename "%%~A" "%%B" "%%C" "%%D" "%%E"
PopD
Goto :Eof

:Rename
: Parse Date to yyMMdd
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%F in (%2) Do Set _YMD=%%H%%F%%G
For /F %%F in (%3) Do Set _DriverNo=%%F
Set _DriverName=%~4
Set _DriverName=%_DriverName: TRUCK=%
Set /A _TruckNo=%~5
Set "NewName=%_YMD%%_DriverName: =-%%_TruckNo%%~x1"
If /i "%~nx1" neq "%NewName%" Echo Ren %1 "%NewName%"
```

Result

```
Ren "Test.txt" "161109-Mike-Smith-4719.txt"
```

**Edit** To really rename the echo in the last line has to be removed. Included an if to prevent renaming an already processed file.

Comment: @Rory Edited the batch and added the hint to remove the echo. If you find the batch usefull you might check the answer and/or vote up. Cheers.